# Python setup.py - install only modifed files

Tags: python, installation, setup.py

Here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys

if sys.version_info < (2, 6):
    sys.exit('requires python 2.6 and up')

package = '*****'
version_string = '0'

setup(name=package,
      version=version_string,
      author='*****',
      author_email='*****',
      url='',
      platforms='Platform Independent',
      tests_require=['nose'],
      test_suite='nose.collector',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['utest']),
      include_package_data=True,
      install_requires=['colorlog', 'netifaces', 'flufl.enum==4.0.1', 'ipaddr', 'rpyc==3.2.3'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Which I have to run every time I make changes in my project even after a small change to a single file, but I have a lot of files in my project that very rarely change. Is there a way to do installation of only modified files?

Comment: Is this during local development. If it is, look at using 'python setup.py develop' rather than 'python setup.py install'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing the code, this is preferable to use `python setup.py develop`. Regarding the files that have to be installed, they are handle by setuptools.

Comment: I've tried running: python setup.py develop, after making changes to a file but it didn't copied the file to /usr/python2.7/site-packages/... as I need.

Comment: It isn't meant to copy the change. The original files are supposed to be symlinked in place in ``site-packages``. If you have previously installed using 'install', you may need to clean up the installed package and start over with 'develop'. Try running ``pip uninstall packagename`` a few times until it says nothing else to remove and then run ``python setup.py develop``. If you still aren't seeing an update, go look at the file in ``site-packages`` and make sure it is a symlink back to the original.